# MSMQ - Receiving message by specific identifier?

Tags: c#, msmq

I recently got into MSMQ. I am trying to receive only specific messages from a queue that has a unique ID.

I tried using CorrelationID for this, but without luck.

```
var message = queue.ReceiveByCorrelationId("12345678901234567890");
```

This would theoretically work, if only I could set the correlation ID of a message myself before sending it. However, I can't.

How can I receive messages only of a specific type that I specify in a queue?

Comment: Can you not use an alternate queue for these specific messages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482254/msmq-get-specific-queue-by-path?noredirect=1#comment30611658_20482254 then this is an issue.